# Prevent empty value in selector (reselect)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, reselect

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

export const selectUser = createSelector(
  [state => state.user],
  user => user
)

const { user } = useSelector(state => selectUser(state))
```

I try to prevent unnecessarily re-rendering in my react application. I want to freeze my `user` object by using `reselect` . But when I load page user object come from back end in async way, and `reselect` freeze this value as `undefined`. How can I prevent it and freeze my `user` object when it already in came from `back-end` and are saved to my `redux` store ?

Comment: Can you create a small demo with your issue please on codesandbox or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

The user was `undefined` because I wasn't correctly retrieved it

```
const user  = useSelector(state => selectUser(state))
```